# Which Birt chart is suitable to following data

Tags: birt

I am new to Birt Tool

my problems is i am unable to match which chart is suitable to my data

please any one suggest me which chart is suitable to my data

my data is

1)  month | submitted | rejected--------------> monthly Reports

2)  date  |  sumbitted | rejected--------------> daily Reports

3)  year  |  sumbitted  | rejected------------> hourly report

Advanced Thanks

Comment: Can you give some real data?  The example you give is hard to extrapolate without context.

Comment: hi MystikSpiral   my data like                               gtAddress month submitted rejected                                                            9555555  2001-01   1000   1000

Answer (score 0):

I like tube charts for this, but line charts can work also.